# If router recieves the source IP 0.0.0.0 then it will forward it or drop it?

Tags: routing

If hacker change the source IP to 0.0.0.0 and checksum is same as previous, then what will be the router do when it recieve this packet???

Comment: Changing anything in the IPv4 header without recalculating the checksum will probably result in the packet being dropped as damaged.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Routers route based on the destination address, so the packet will be forwarded normally.  But if you change the header and don't recalculate the checksum, the packet will be dropped.

Many routers can be configured to route based on other criteria.  For example, you can read about Cisco's Policy-based Routing.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the security policy of your router. Under normal circumstances, 0.0.0.0 should never be seen. And it's technically invalid in a unicast packet -- zero is never a valid return address. [i.e. if anyone on the internet is claiming to be 0.0.0.0, you know they're lying.]

The only place it would normally ever exist is during the stages of DHCP address negotiation. And there it's commonly only seen in broadcast traffic. (L2 and/or L3)